# type of missing value in Julia, like NA_real_

Tags: julia

I am unable to specify type of missing data.

> Julia provides support for representing missing values in the statistical sense, that is for situations where no value is available for a variable in an observation, but a valid value theoretically exists.

According to above description copied from Julia manual I would expect I can create `missing` objects of different types. I am getting following error:

```
missing::Real
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Real, got Missing
```

Type of object is useful information to carry along with missingness, do I need to carry that in a separate variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a singleton type `Missing` whose only instance is value `missing` that represents a missing value in Julia. Therefore, as opposed to R, there is no distinction between a missing of type float, logical etc.

The reason for such a design is that in Julia you can define your own type so it is not possible to list all possible types of missing like in R.

You can check this by writing:

```
julia> missing isa Missing
true

julia> supertype(Missing)
Any
```

Typically collections allowing missing value have an element type of `Union{Missing, Actual_Type_You_Want}` for instance:

```
julia> [1, 2, missing]
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
  missing

julia> Dict(1=>1, 2=>missing)
Dict{Int64,Union{Missing, Int64}} with 2 entries:
  2 => missing
  1 => 1
```

In theory it would be possible to define a parametric type `Missing{T}` that would carry the type `T` information but it would not be very convenient to use in practice as then you would have to have a separate syntax for each type of missing value, and currently it is enough to write `missing` and you have what you want.

Note that this is exactly what most R users do anyway as when they write `NA` it is of logical type and it gets converted under the hood following the collection type it is put into. You can see `NA_real_` and similar very rarely in actual R code from my experience.

Comment: Dzieki for detailed explanation. I agree that NA_type_ is rarely used in R, although IMO it should be used more often. In Julia I was expecting types to be even more important because if I declare output of a function `f()::Real = ...` I cannot return `missing` from it. And AFAIK it is good practice (for performance reasons) to be type strict in Julia.

Comment: Agreed - declaring types is a good practice and a big thing why I user Julia. You can define return type as `f()::Union{Real, Missing}` in such a case. In the future probably some syntactic sugar for this will be introduced, most probably `Real?` or something like this. Moreover you can even write `const RealMissing = Union{Real, Missing}` to avoid writing `Union` even now. Finally note that type assertion like `f()::T` first tries to convert return value of `f()` to `T` so actually it is more like casting it to `T`. E.g. function ` g(x)::Float64 = x` when called `g(1)` will return `1.0`.

Comment: Being type stable and annotating types is two different things. My code can be perfectly type stable and fast without any type annotations. So I don't think that explicit return type annotations are generally good practice.

Comment: You do not need type annotations for type stability, but they are useful for catching bugs. Also there are some functions that cannot be made type stable and you still want to ensure that they return a correct type so that type instability does not propagate (this is what sometimes happens e.g. when you use DataFrames.jl that do not provide type stability of columns). Of course this is optional.